# Style the label in php

Tags: php, html, css, styles

**Scenario :**

- To Style label

**Here is my code to view status**

```
<?php
    if ($shift['isActive'] == 1) {
        echo 'Active';
    } else {
        echo 'Inactive';
    } 
?>
```

**Problem :**

- Is there have any way to style the label Active & 
  Inactive separately(background color).

Comment: With css classes.

Comment: Please clarify it

Comment: `<li class="<?= ($shift['isActive'] == 1) ? 'active':'inactive'; ?>">`

Comment: try `label.isActive {background: black;}` and `label.inactive {background: red;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
if ($shift['isActive'] == 1) {
    echo "<lable style='background-color: green;'>Active</lable>";
} else {
    echo "<lable style='background-color: red;'>Inactive</lable>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
<div class="<?php $shift['isActive'] == 1 ? 'Active' : 'Inactive' ?>">
    something
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<label class="<?php if ($shift['isActive'] == 1) { echo 'Active'; } else {echo 'Inactive'; } ?>">
</label>
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer requires an explanation how the problem is solved.